# Winform Button.Click not fired when I insert a break point at WM_PARENTNOTIFY

Tags: c#, winforms, wndproc

My Button.Click is not firing if I override WndProc and insert a break point at WM_PARENTNOTIFY.
It fires if I subsequently remove the break point and click on the button again.

Does anyone know why is this happening? Thanks.

```
[System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    switch (m.Msg)
    {
        case WM_PARENTNOTIFY:
            break;
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: The breakpoint causes the window to lose focus, switching it to VS.  That cancels the mouse capture, required to reliably detect the MouseUp notification.  Thus no Click event.  Very tough cases may require remote debugging, weapon of last choice.  Setting the breakpoint in a smarter way, including making it conditional, is what you always contemplate first.  Debug.WriteLine(m); can be quite handy too.

Comment: Oh!! That explains it.
I actually do not need to debug it, it was by chance that I discovered this behaviour, and wanted to know why it behaves the way it does.
I've also verified what you said by hooking to Button.MouseDown instead, and it does get fired with break point.
How do I accept your comment as the answer?